# Calculate latitude and longitude based on zip code using cloud pages in salesforce marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

I would like to calculate latitude and longitude using zip code. I am able to various links on how to calculate it in salesforce, but nothing using cloud pages.

Looking for some help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You generally have to purchase zipcode data that contains latitude and longitude values.

Once you have it, you can calculate the X, Y, and Z-Axis values you need to utilize it using Query Activities:

```sql
select
zip
, cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude))  xaxis
, cos(radians(latitude)) * sin(radians(longitude))  yaxis
, sin(radians(latitude))  zaxis
from zip_axis
/* credit https://stackoverflow.com/a/2233208/812377 */
```

There are more details and an overall offline solution for SFMC over here on my blog:

https://sprignaturemoves.com/geolocation-in-sfmc/

If you need a live geolocation solution, I think it's most common to integrate with a third-party solution like [Google's Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/overview).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update :)